# Don't know how to start a multi search criteria in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet where I am trying to do some calculations based on multiple search criteria and have no idea where to start. I would like the first part of the vba to pull row values so I could go from there. I've looked at other threads but couldn't figure out how to apply them.

The excel sheet looks something like this

```
 Date  | Name | Location | Components | Composition

1/2/19    T1       S1       Hexane           5%
1/2/19    T1       S1       Water           20%
1/2/19    T1       S1       Benzene         75%
1/2/19    T2       S1       Water           100% 
.
.
.
```

So I'm trying to write a code that will return for all rows where the Date, Name, and Location column are matches so that I can create a column stating if their compositions =100%, and then run some calculations. There's about 2000 rows so any way to automate it would be awesome.

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sumifs()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a simple [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) function to do this. Create another table with the specific date, name, and location values that you want to see and one more column for total composition.

In the total composition column you could write a SUMIFs statement like this.

```
=SUMIFS(YourCompositionColumnRange, YourDateColumnRange,"=" & YourDateValue, YourNameColumnRange,"=" & YourNameValue, YourLocationColumnRange,"=" & YourLocationValue)
```

Where the column ranges are the named ranges representing your data columns and the value ranges are the named ranges representing your values that you want to sum over.

If you're not super familiar with VBA this will be the fastest solution for you.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I don't know all the values since there's over 2000 of them. I have some programming experience with Python and Matlab so I was hoping there was some sort of logic in vba that could do this.

Comment: Then you are going to want to pull the range of data into an array and loop through it to create a second array into which, you will load the unique date, name, location pairs and sum the composition. Its pretty straight forward, if you've used matlab then you should be pretty familiar with this sort of data processing although Matlab does have a lot better array functions ready to hand then VBA if I recall.